# How to make a condition out of the selected listbox item?

Tags: c#, listbox

I can't believe I got drained by this small problem trying to find the solution playing with the intellisense. No luck  Just starting c# GUI. Just need a quick answer please.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedValue== "Chicken")
{
    total += 15;
    ord += " Chicken";
    label4.Text = "chicken selected";
}
```

what the hell is wrong with this.
I want to execute the statements when the user selected the item "chicken" from listbox1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double total = 0;
    int x = 0;
    string ord = "";

    private void placeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
        listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            total += 1;
            ord += " Water";
        }
        if (checkBox1.Text == "Extra Meat")
        {
            total += 1;
            ord += ord+" Extra Meat ";
        }
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Extra Rice")
        {
            total += 1;
            ord += " Extra Rice";

        }
        if (comboBox1.Text == "Extra Veggies")
        {
            total += 1;
            ord +=" Extra Veggies";
        }

        if (listBox1.SelectedValue== "Chicken")
        { 
            total+=15;
            ord+=" Chicken";
            label4.Text = "chicken selected";
        }
        if (listBox1.Text == "Pizza    $8")  //< my pathetic attempt to figure it out with intelisense
        { 
            total+=8;
            ord+="Pizza ";
            label4.Text = "qwe";
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Spaghetti     $12")//< my pathetic attempt to figure it out with intelisense
        { 
            total+=12;
            ord+=" Spaghetti";
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Fries              $8")
        { 
            total+=8;
            ord+=" Fries";
        }
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Burger          $10")
        { 
            total+=10;
            ord+=" Burger";
        }

        //radiobutton
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        { 
            total+=5;
            ord += " Pineapple Juice";
        }
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            total+=6;
            ord += " Mango Juice";
        }
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            total+=7;
            ord += " Apple Juice";
        }
        if (radioButton4.Checked)
        {
            total+=8;
            ord += " Orange Juice";
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Order Done");
    }

    private void clearToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ord = "";
        total = 0;
    }

    private void displayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Order: " + ord+"\nTotal: "+total);
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem coming?

Comment: Show some context. When is this code running?

Comment: What's the error? Where are total and ord declared?

Comment: The answer depends on what you have added to the ListBox. Strings? Some Objects?

Answer (score 1):

You code cannot work, since you clear all the selections before you are processing the order. Move this code to the very end of the `placeToolStripMenuItem_Click` method:

```
// Process the order here ...
MessageBox.Show("Order Done");

checkBox1.Checked = false;
radioButton1.Checked = false;
radioButton2.Checked = false;
radioButton3.Checked = false;
radioButton4.Checked = false;
listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

---

I think that your approach is wrong. You should not have to make all these `if`-statements. Instead create a `Product` class

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}    ${1}", Name, Price);
    }
}
```

Then add products to your listbox:

```
listbox1.Items.Add(new Product{ Name = "Chicken", Price = 15 });
listbox1.Items.Add(new Product{ Name = "Pizza", Price = 8 });
...
```

Then you can work with the selected item like this:

```
var product = listBox1.SelectedItem as Product;
if (product != null) {
    total += product.Price;
    ord += " " + product.Name;
    label4.Text = product.Name + " selected";
}
```

Also declare `total` as `decimal`. Doubles are good for scientific calculations, but can easily yield results like `7.49999999` instead of `7.5`. Decimals have been introduced especially for currency calculations. They are not very fast but they don't convert decimal numbers into binary numbers internally, instead the decimal digits are preserved. The problem with binary numbers is that for instance 1/10 cannot be represented accurately just like 1/3 cannot be represented accurately in the decimal system.

---

You can even add products to your radio buttons

```
radioButton3.Tag = new Product{ Name = "Apple Juice", Price = 7 };
```

A more advanced method would be to create your own radio button control with a `Product` property, but this solution will do it for now.

Then you can loop through all your radio buttons like this

```
foreach (var radioButton in Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()) {
    if (radioButton.Checked) {
        var p = (Product)radioButton.Tag;
        total += p.Price;
        ord += " " + p.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have just started c# so I am aware that my approach is questionable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SelectedItem.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Chicken")
```

Answer (score 0):

My program is throwing a Nullreferenceexception on me.
on this line:
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Chicken $15")
I have to initialize it i guess but i have no idea how to initialize a listBox.

Answer (score -2):

**First Method:**

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)    //first check if any item is selected
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Chicken")
```

**Second Method:**

```
if (listBox1.Text == "Chicken")
```

**and** just remove the line:

```
private void placeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();    //remove this line
```

It clears your selected items, that's why you are not getting into any `if` condition.

Comment: how can i make this work bro?  it doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you remove the line?

Comment: but now how do i unselect the item when the button is clicked?

Comment: When you show the message, `Order done`. You can place that line after that message box display.